# 'Than me' or 'than yours'

Tags: pronouns

I found this question in an exercise book and unsatisfied with the provided answer:

Her writing is better than ____.

A. he

B. she

C. yours

D. me

The provided answer is D but I answered C. Help, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies in advance for an unhelpful answer: The question is a bad one, or at least badly presented.

As a native (American) English speaker, I would have answered the same way you did.

"Yours" is a possessive predicate adjective. It must have an antecedent, a thing that it is describing, and as it is possessive, this antecedent must belong to "you". As there is no noun for your "yours" would be placed in the blank, it would imply a comparison between "her writing" and "your writing", so the sentence would be valid and equivalent to "Her writing is better than your writing".

According to the listed answer ("me"), the speaker is comparing himself or herself unfavorably to "her writing". This to me is very convoluted to me. If the speaker was comparing their own writing unfavorably to "her writing", a native speaker would still not use "me" but rather the possessive "mine".

In summary, I think your choice was correct and the listed answer was wrong.